# Showing error on live server i.e Forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, permissions

My website is running fine on localhost but on live server it is showing an error i.e.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /package-booking.php on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This error is showing after following 3-4 next pages from index.php page. I have also changes the public_html's all directory permission to 0755 and files to 0644 but still facing the same problem. Please help me out, I am poorly stuck in it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tried to setup the .htaccess file?

Comment: i have created .htaccess file and have the code 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d